# Passing of a method as delegate to referenced module

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, architecture

My **App.Api** project has a **AppService** project as a reference in Visual Studio as seen in the figure below. App.Api can access AppService classes and methods, but AppService cannot access Api.Api classes and methods. They both are build into separate DLL-files.

[image: Reference]

I have a static method in App.Api that I need to call in the AppService module. I'm able to pass it as a delegate to AppService and it is working perfectly. The implementation of that method needs to be placed in App.Api for other reasons that are too long to explain here.

Can any problems occur with this kind of solution? Is this even an appropriate way to do things architecturally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This denotes problem of circular reference and design flaw.
You need mediator to communicate between these two layers or need abstraction which will be shared by two layers.

Comment: By this method AppService lose its usability for other projects.

Comment: If design is having flaw, usability will be anyway impacted in near future.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). App.api `subscribes` in AppService and when is needed it will `notify` App.api.